# Como garantir a segurança de uma senha ao extrair uma SecureString em C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gerenciamento-de-memória

Estava lendo sobre SecureString e o que ela pode oferecer. Entretanto, estou em um cenário onde possuo uma PasswordBox e desejo extrair a senha desse componente, codifica-la em hash e depois compará-la com outra senha codificada contida em um banco de dados, para então efetuar um sistema simples de login.

Li que utilizar a propriedade Password não é uma boa ideia, pois uma vez que a manipulamos, estamos sujeitos a ter essa senha roubada, já que os dados de uma string existem na memória.

Considerando que uma string é um objeto presente em memória gerenciada, como posso garantir a extração segura de uma senha de uma SecureString, gerando também o mínimo de copias possíveis em memória? Ou isso também não é uma boa ideia?

Comment: Não sei se entendi a dúvida,  o que quer saber, a não ser que queira algo impossível. o que leu sore a `SecureString`? O que pode dizer para melhorar a compreensão do que deseja? Quer saber se tem como fazer algo 100% seguro?

Comment: Isso, ou pelo menos a maneira mais segura possível